# How to end an infinite while loop by quitting application

Tags: c++

I am trying to determine if the user wants to quit, and thus return true or false based on that.

On return to the while loop, I should be able to handle accordingly to enable the user to gracefully quit on his or her own choice. Please help.

My main function code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "EverTrueHelper.h"
        
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "I am for ever true unless you fix me" << endl;
    string myNameForEver = "khadijah kamba 3901";
    cout << "My Awesome Name is " << myNameForEver << endl;
    //
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double result = 0.0;
    string userEntry;
    char oper = '+';

    cout << "Calculator Console Application" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the operation to perform. Format: a+b | a-b | a*b | a/b" << endl;

    EverTrueHelper everTRueHelperObj;
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> x >> oper >> y;
        if (oper == '/' && y == 0)
        {
            cout << "Division by 0 exception" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            result = everTRueHelperObj.calculate(x, oper, y);
        }
        cout << "Result is: " << result << endl;
        //
        //check if user wants to quit
        //Call method getAndReturnUserEntry()
        //if return is true, end else continue
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `.cpp` of my class is:

```cpp
#include "EverTrueHelper.h"
#include <string>
    
char EverTrueHelper::quitOrContinue(char userEntry)
{
    return 0;
}

double EverTrueHelper::calculate(double x, char oper, double y)
{
    switch (oper)
    {
        case '+':
            return x + y;
        case '-':
            return x - y;
        case '*':
            return x * y;
        case '/':
            return x / y;
        default:
            return 0.0;
    }
}

bool EverTrueHelper::getAndReturnUserEntry(string userEntry)
{
    if (userEntry == "Q" || userEntry == "q")
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the header of my class is:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class EverTrueHelper
{
private: 
    char quitOrContinue(char userEntry);
public:
    double calculate(double x, char oper, double y);
    bool getAndReturnUserEntry(string userEntry);    
};
```

Comment: "How to end an infinite loop?" Why is NOT making it infinite not the answer? I.e. replace `true`with a condition describing when you still need the loop, and implicitly when you do not need it anymore via negation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
while (true)
```

For better readabillity I would rename `quitOrContinue` to `keepRunning`. `quitOrContinue` is rather ambigous, because when one reads that name, it's not clear if true is returned to quit or to continue. One have to look at the code to know it.

And then you can use

```
while(!everTrueHelperObj.keepRunning(userEntry))
```

Alternatively you can use a `break`

```
while (true)
{
    if(!everTrueHelperObj.keepRunning(userEntry))
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have shown, as there is nothing after the `while` loop except the `return 0;` statement, then a simple `break;` will exit the loop and, thus, exit the program. Reduced to a minimal sample:

```cpp
bool checkCondition();

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        // Do something
        if (!checkCondition()) break; // exit loop if function returns false
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, for a more general case, you can exit the program (from within the `main` function) at *any point* using a `return n;` statement (where the value of the `n` integer is passed to the operating system as an 'exit status' code):

```cpp
bool checkCondition();

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        // Do something
        if (!checkCondition()) return 0; // exit program (don't do "something else").
    }
    // Do something else...
    return 0;
}
```

To terminate a program from another function (i.e. *not* `main`) then you can call the the [`std::exit(n)` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), which has a very similar effect to a `return n;` statement inside `main`.